# How to run a python script inside aws server from webpage?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have a python script inside an AWS server. I need to build a webpage that'll have a form with submit buttons which when clicked must run the python script.

Can this be made possible by building an S3 static website with the form/button? If not, what would be better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You will need something to handle HTTP requests. Take a look at the [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), it's super easy framework for Python.